# A fight between Dr Manhattan and Electro from Spider-Man

Tags: dc, spider-man, marvel, watchmen

As the title suggests, in a fight between Dr Manhattan from The Watchmen and Electro from the recently released movie Spider-Man 2, who'd win and why?

Comment: Gorilla vs. Shark questions are considered to be off - topic

Comment: For explanation, here is [the original post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) on it.

Comment: Just because they both have blue-colored powers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering Dr Manhattan can alter reality itself, he can change anyone into anything or move them anywhere.... only trouble is, he probably could not be bothered because he mostly doesn't care one way or the other. It's not really a fair fight I guess lol... it is more like putting Q versus Superman.

But IF Dr. Manhattan could be bothered and actually fought he'd likely teleport them both to the floor of the Mariana Trench and gleefully watch as Electro short circuits himself and drowns. Or onto the surface of the sun or whatever.